# How to hide MYSQL credentials in SQLAlchemy using Flask application

Tags: python, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using MySQL for my Flask application; but I need help for hiding the password in the MySQL user credentials

Currently it's like this

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql+pymysql://iaflask:Flask123@localhost/my_database"
```

Is there a way to hide the username:password (iaflask:Flask123) or at least just to hide the password within the code.

Comment: Usual strategy is to read from environment variable. Or a config file. ie. Store the credential as environment variable permanently and then read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES into your config file...

i.e `export SQL_URI="YOUR URI HERE"`

And then use:

`app.config["SQL_URI"] = os.getenv("SQL_URI")`

That way your secret_keys, password or URI's can be hidden from source code. In production you will need to store these ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES again either in the platforms vars or in the servers environments.

Comment: Sorry for a late response, just applied this and thank you, this is what I wanted. Can you also tell me where can I verify the variable? or look to edit it? I tried looking in `printenv` output but I couldn't find the SQL_URI

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use `getpass` to not hardcode the password itself (or a hash).

Example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql, getpass

password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql+pymysql://iaflask:" + password + "@localhost/my_database"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, go with having an encrypted value with a secret key for different dev environments and store these keys in the config file and change it when deploying on production with production secret key. I use something like below

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

msg_text = 'text to convert'.rjust(32)
secret_key = '' # create new & store somewhere safe

cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB) # never use ECB in strong systems obviously
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg_text))
print encoded
# ...
decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encoded))
print decoded.strip()
```